# what causes syntax error in django-urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
enter code here from django.conf.urls import url
                from .import views
                urlpatterns = [
                    url(r'^$', views.item, name='item')
                    url(r'^p/(<p>\d+)$', views.item2, name='item2')
                    url(r'^p/new/$', views.item3, name='item3')
```

I'm getting a syntaxError: invalid syntax from the last url line I entered don't know what's causing this

Answer (score 1):

Adding a comma should help after each URL pattern should help,

```
url(r'^$', views.item, name='item'),
```

If it doesn't please post a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Django are you using?

> If you are using Django < 2.0, your urlpatterns look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.item, name='item'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d)/$', views.item, name='item'),
    url(r'/news/$', views.item3, name='item3')
]
```

> If you are using Django >= 2.2

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.item, name='item'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.item, name='item'),
    path('news/', views.item3, name='item3')
]
```